# Find first match following another string, python regex multiline

Tags: python, regex

I know many flavors of these questions have been asked, but I am having a bit of trouble getting a regex statement working to address my specific problem.

I have a large number of functions with different names but the exact same format and I need to find the first match following a specific function name.

Note that I am searching through a C file using python.

```
 writecwp_positionStatus(int      action,
        u_char   *var_val,
        u_char   var_val_type,
        size_t   var_val_len,
        u_char   *statP,
        oid      *name,
        size_t   name_len) {

static long     intval;
static long     old_intval;

switch ( action ) {
    case RESERVE1:
      if (var_val_type != ASN_INTEGER) {
          fprintf(stderr, "write to mib not ASN_INTEGER\n");
          return SNMP_ERR_WRONGTYPE;
      }
      if (var_val_len > sizeof(long)) {
          fprintf(stderr,"write to mib: bad length\n");
          return SNMP_ERR_WRONGLENGTH;
      }
    intval = *((long *) var_val);
      break;

    case RESERVE2:
      break;

    case FREE:
         /* Release any resources that have been allocated */
      break;

    case ACTION:
         /*
          * The variable has been stored in 'value' for you to use,
          * and you have just been asked to do something with it.
          * Note that anything done here must be reversable in the UNDO case
          */
        old_intval = starting_int;
        starting_int = intval;
      break;

    case UNDO:
         /* Back out any changes made in the ACTION case */
         starting_int = old_intval;
      break;

    case COMMIT:
         /*
          * Things are working well, so it's now safe to make the change
          * permanently.  Make sure that anything done here can't fail!
          */
      break;
} return SNMP_ERR_NOERROR;
```

}

In this example I want to find the first "old_intval = starting_int;" following the function name "writecwp_positionStatus".  There will be many more functions with the same exact body but different names.

My thought was to set up a capture group to match:

```
(function name)(everything in between including newlines)(line to replace)
```

I tried a bunch of different options such as, but seem to be off by just a little each time:

```
(writecwp_positionStatus\(.*\s)((.*\s)*?)(\s*old_intval = starting_int;)
```

Comment: are you including the `re.DOTALL` flag? without it, `(.*?)` won't capture newlines...

Comment: Parsing code (or any multi-level/hierarchical structure for that matter) with regex is a very bad idea. I can write a dozen or so examples where any pattern you may think of will fail to capture what you're looking for. What exactly are you trying to achieve here? If you want to comprehend the code using a dedicated C parser, like the [`pycparser`](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser) would be far more suitable.

Comment: I have auto-generated C code that I need to update based on dynamic function names and I am doing it with python.  I need pattern matching, this isn't a time or performance stringent operation as its just a 1 time setup script.  I think regex is fully appropriate for what I need, below answer worked well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this regex instead.

```
(writecwp_positionStatus[\s\S]*?)old_intval = starting_int;([\s\S]*)
```

Here, the approach is to capture everything from the function-name to the statement to be repalaced by *capture group 01* and then match everything after the staement by *capture group 02*

```
\s -> whitespace character (a space, a tab, a line break, or a form feed).
\S -> non-white space character.
*? -> ? after quantifiers makes them lazy/non-greedy.
```

Now to replace the statement, we can use another regex:

```
\1 >>>I am the replacement<<< \2
```

Here,

```
\1 -> Everything before the statement.
\2 -> Everything after the statement.
```

To understand better, do experiments [here](https://regex101.com/r/GmVxUl/1). I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Though this answer will satisfy this particular case, parsing source code using regex would not be a good idea. Follow @zwer's advice in the comments of the question.